# How to use each() with mouseenter, mouseover and data attributes right

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a block which has some data attributes:

```
<div class="my-div" data-color="#ff4b4b" data-hover="#000">
    Text
</div>
```

Now I want to use javascript for changing text color on mouseenter and mouseover using my data attributes.
So I have:

```
$(".my-div").each(function() {
    $(this).mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).css('color', this.dataset.hover);
    });
    $(this).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).css('color', this.dataset.color);
    });
});
```

If I have one div, it's working fine, but if I have another divs with the same class, and I mouseenter and mouseover one div, another divs react too.
What should I do to make it working right, maybe add an index, I don't know.
Can you help me, please?

Thanks in advance. Sorry for my English.

P.S. Don't advise css, for this I must use javascript.

Comment: Using the code snippets you provided works as expected. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c2v6wpgq/).

Comment: @AdamH Sorry, guys, I wrote right code, because I shortened code and forgot that on mouseenter and mouseover I should target inside this div <p> tag, but all data attributes should be saved inside div. I'm writing another question right now. I can't delete this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the target element of the event passed into each handler using `$(this)`:

```js
$(".my-div").each(function() {
    $(this).mouseenter(function(e) {
        $(this).css('color', this.dataset.hover);
    });
    $(this).mouseleave(function(e) {
        $(this).css('color', this.dataset.color);
    });
});
```

```css
.my-div{
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="my-div" data-color="black" data-hover="red">
    Text 1
</div>

<div class="my-div" data-color="black" data-hover="green">
    Text 2
</div>

<div class="my-div" data-color="black" data-hover="blue">
    Text 3
</div>
```

Comment: The creation of `el` is redundant. Can you just have `$(e.target).css('color', this.dataset.hover);`

Comment: Also jquery sets the context to the element that triggered the event so `this` is still valid.

Comment: @Kousha you're right. I edited my answer to show that. Thanks.

Comment: And now your code is exactly what was posted as not working lol. Except for the css.

Comment: @AdamH LMAO what!?

Comment: Compare your JS to the JS OP posted, it is identical.

Comment: @AdamH No I know lol, I'm just confused why he had a problem with the code

Comment: I'm convinced the problem is in code that isn't posted.

Comment: When I was writing a question I has another code, so I forgot to write, that on mouseenter and mouseover I'm changing <p> tag inside this div, but all attributes still inside that div. So code I've written should work.

Comment: Sorry, guys., it's my fault.

Comment: @symlink also micro-optimization, but you can have `function onEvent(e) { $(this).css('color', this.dataset.hover); }` so then just do `$(this).mouseenter(onEvent);` for both events so they both use the same code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work by itself but you don't need to loop through each div to check if the mouse has entered or left each `div` element - it's extremely inefficient.

So remove:

```
$(".my-div").each(function() {});
```

Your new code should look like the following:

```js
$(".my-div").mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).css('color', this.dataset.hover);
});
$(".my-div").mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).css('color', this.dataset.color);
});
```

```css
.my-div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #ff4b4b;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="my-div" data-color="#ff4b4b" data-hover="#000">
  Text
</div>
<div class="my-div" data-color="#ff4b4b" data-hover="#000">
  Text
</div>
<div class="my-div" data-color="#ff4b4b" data-hover="#000">
  Text
</div>
```

Obviously the CSS isn't necessary but I have added it to prove that it works correctly.